# Why is the region in Drupal blank?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I my .info file I have this:

```
regions[footermenu] = Footer Menu
```

The region--footer.tp.php has this:

```
<?php
    print render($page['footermenu']);
?>
```

I've placed a menu block in the "Footer Menu" (it shows up under structure->blocks). However, it's blank. If I place the block in region I know works the menu content is seen fine. Any idea why the region wouldn't see the block?

Answer (score 1):

as your question doesn't have any proper explanation, people most likely cant help you. but I can guess that what you are doing wrong is that you make a `region--footer.tpL.php` file (you missed the L in the end), you also need to render it on the page you want it there to be, so practically it wont show you anything since its not rendering at all.

my suggestion is forget about `region--footer.tpl.php` and add

```
<?php
    print render($page['footermenu']);
?>
```

right into your `page.tpl.php` or any other theme hooks you might want it there.

by the way a very rookie mistake is that you already done everything right but after editing your `.info` file you forgot to clear the cache in `admin/config/settings/development/performance`